# Python input validation loop infinitely loops

Tags: validation, input, while-loop, infinite-loop, python-3.3

I'm attempting to utilize TeamTreehouse learning subscription & this Starting Out With Programming Logic And Design book to attempt learning programming & python. Currently I'm onto learning input validation which honestly appears more straightforward than I'd presumed it's just adding a purpose to loops/functions.

Goal: To build out a program that will calculate an employee's gross pay via asking them for the inputs of hours worked as well as their pay rate. I've decided a while loop is less code (I could stand to be corrected though that's my perspective at this time) than writing this out as an if/else loop. At the time of writing this I don't have it fully built other than building & testing my first input validation loop.

Error: **My payRates while loop never exits/ends whether I enter -10, 14 or 99 which I suspect has to do with setting it to check for multiple conditions?** From the cross reference tutorial I found on while loops (url below) I don't see any "end while" command I have to wrap the command in (book is based on theory/pseudocode) whereas I'm not finding much substance material on multiple condition while loops.

While Loop Tutorial
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

Python Code
URL http://repl.it/mwU

```
#///////////Variable Declarations///////////
payRates=0
hoursWorked=0
#///////////Variable Declarations///////////

#///////////payRates Input Validation///////////
def payRate():
    payrate=input("Please enter your payrate.")
    while payRates < float(7.50) or payRate > float(18.25):
#    while payRates<7.50:# or payRates>18.25:
        print("That is an invalid payrate, valid payrates are $7.50-$18.25.")
        payrate=input("Please enter a valid payrate.")

#///////////payRates Input Validation///////////

#///////////hoursWorked Input Validation///////////
#while hoursWorked<0: or hoursWorked>40:
#    print("That is an invalid amount of hours worked, a valid range is 0-40.")
#    int(hoursWorked=input("Please enter valid hours worked.")    
#///////////hoursWorked Input Validation///////////

payRate()
print(payRates)
print(hoursWorked)
```

Comment: There is `payRates` and `payrate`, which one do you want to check?

Comment: `while payRates < float(7.50) or payRate > float(18.25)` you are using `payRates` camelCase which you never set. your variable from input is `payrate` lowercase. Check for `payRate` the method name used incorrectly too.

Comment: Oh my goodness I had my variables typed in wrong.  I'm just going to get in the practice of declaring variables then copy pasting them from declaration zone into where they need to used. I do encounter a new error though

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 21, in <module>
  File "python", line 9, in payRate
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()

Comment: Ah ha I had formatted my input/variables as float in the wrong area. Has to be payRates=float(input("Please enter a valid payrate.")) versus float(payRates=input("Please enter a valid payrate.")) though wouldn't it be the same either way as in the last code bit I'm formatting everything in the float paranthesis as float?

Comment: Please correct the code in your question, which should ideally have been pasted from your program